# clang-format incorrect formatting of proto files

Tags: protocol-buffers, clang-format, protocol-buffers-3

Using clang-format 17 with the following `.clang-format` file:

```
# other languages ...
---
Language: "Proto"
BasedOnStyle: Google
UseTab: Never
TabWidth: 4
LineEnding: LF
InsertNewlineAtEOF: true
ColumnLimit: 120
IndentWidth: 4
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: AcrossEmptyLinesAndComments
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: AcrossEmptyLinesAndComments
AlignTrailingComments: true
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
...
```

I get the following:

```
message AssignUserTickets
{
    int64    user_id                               = 1;
    int64    ticket_type_id                        = 2;
    optional google.protobuf.Timestamp expires_at  = 3;
    int32                              num_tickets = 4;
}
```

When the expected result is:

```
message AssignUserTickets
{
    int64                              user_id        = 1;
    int64                              ticket_type_id = 2;
    optional google.protobuf.Timestamp expires_at     = 3;
    int32                              num_tickets    = 4;
}
```

Removing the `optional` keyword gives the desired formatting, but we don't want to do that<sup>1</sup>.

How can I achieve the desired formatting without changing the message definition?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> I know that `optional` is not required in this case, since `Timestamp` is a `Message` and therefore [has explicit presence](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/docs/field_presence.md) by default, but we still want to use it for consistency with simple types and as documentation to the user of the protocol that omitting it has specific meaning.</sup>

Comment: `optional` was added to proto 3 only at v 3.15. It sure looks like the indent logic hasn't been updated for it, at least correctly. File a bug?

Comment: `BreakBeforeBraces: Allman
AcrossEmptyLinesAndComments` - this doesn't look like a valid config file. Perhaps, further lines are ignored.

Comment: @273K Editing error while cleaning up comments from the original file. Fixed.

Comment: @Gene `optional` seems to format correctly with builtin types